# surface integral parametrization, understanding steps

Tags: mathematical-physics, surface-integrals, parametrization

Hello I'm trying to understand the following "proof" from E&M Griffiths where $V$ is the potential, for an integral over a spherical surface
\begin{align}
V_{\text{ave}}(R) &= \frac{1}{4 \pi R^{2}} \int V(\boldsymbol{r}) \ da \\
&= \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int V(R,\theta,\phi) \ \sin \theta \ d\theta \ d\phi \\
\frac{d V_{\text{ave}}}{d R} &= \frac{1}{4\pi } \int \frac{\partial V}{\partial R} \sin \theta \ d\theta \ d\phi \tag{1}\\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi} \int (\nabla V \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{r}}) \ \sin \theta  \ d\theta \ d\phi \tag{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi R^{2}} \int(\nabla V) \cdot (R^{2} \ \sin \theta \ d\theta \ d\phi 
 \ \boldsymbol{\hat{r}}) \tag{3}\\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi R^{2}} \int (\nabla V ) \cdot d \boldsymbol{a} \\
&= \frac{1}{4 \pi R^{2}} \int (\nabla^{2}V) \ d\tau =0
\end{align}

#### Elements of confusion

In $(1)$ I'm not sure to understand what what allows me to bring the derivative inside the integral.

In $(2)$ I don't understand at all the equality
$$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial R} = (\nabla V \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{r}}),$$
I suspect this is because the parametrization is with respect to $\theta $ and $\phi$ , such that the extra variable $R$ is the normal vector with respect to the surface we're integrating over, hence the dot product ?

In $(3)$ Why does the $R^{2}$ and $\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}$ suddenly appear in the $d\boldsymbol{a}$ integral element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is a direct application of the [Leibinz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)
2. In [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)

$$
\nabla V = {\partial V \over \partial R}\hat{\mathbf r}
+ {1 \over r}{\partial V \over \partial \theta}\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}
+ {1 \over r\sin\theta}{\partial V \over \partial \varphi}\hat{\boldsymbol \varphi}
$$

if you multiply both sides by $\hat{\mathbf r}$ you will get

$$
\hat{\mathbf r} \cdot \nabla V = (\hat{\mathbf r} \cdot \hat{\mathbf r}) \frac{\partial V}{\partial R} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial R}
$$

3. Since you're on a surface of constant radius, you can multiply and divide by $R$ since it is just a constant

Comment: Awesome this checks out thank you !

Comment: @hitechphysics Happy to help